# So I am practicing inheritance for my school Assignment but I am not being able to properly implement the header guards

Tags: c++

I have a base class card with basic card attributes. In main I get an error of redefinition as the class CallingCard and the IDCard both are inheriting the base class Card. I have tried using header guards but I am not being able to properly implement them. Also in main while using a G++ compiler, I need to include ".cpp" instead of ".h" as including ".h" gives me an error

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

_main in main-ad117f.o
  (int, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allo
cator >, int, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, int)", referenced from:

_main in main-ad117f.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It could not be header guards and could be the inclusion of ".cpp" instead of ".h" in main but that gives me an error I don't know how to fix
Please help me out to fix whatever the problem is, be it header guards or including ".cpp" instead of ".h"

Card.h

This is my base class

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
#ifndef CARD_H           //Header guards or pragma once? and how to implement?
#define CARD_H
class Card
{
    private:
    int cardNumber;
    protected:
    string ownerName;
    public:
    string expiryDate;
    Card(int cardNumber=0, string ownerName="Non", string expiryDate="0");
    void display();
};
#endif
```

Card.cpp

```
#include"Card.h"
Card::Card(int cardNumber, string ownerName, string expiryDate)
{
    this->cardNumber=cardNumber;
    this->ownerName=ownerName;
    this->expiryDate=expiryDate;
}

void Card::display()
{
    cout<<"Card Number: "<<this->cardNumber<<endl;
    cout<<"Owner Name: "<<this->ownerName<<endl;
    cout<<"Expiry Date: "<<this->expiryDate<<endl;
}
```

CallingCard.h

This is a child class inheriting from base class

```
#include"Card.cpp"
#ifndef CALLINGCARD_H
#define CALLINGCARD_H
class CallingCard :
        public Card
{
    private:
    int amount;
    string companyName;
    int PIN;
    public:
    CallingCard(int cardNumber, string ownerName, string expiryDate, int amount=0, string companyName="Non", int PIN=0);
    void display();

};
#endif
```

CallingCard.cpp

```
#include"CallingCard.h"
CallingCard::CallingCard(int cardNumber, string ownerName, string expiryDate, int amount, string companyName, int PIN):Card(cardNumber,ownerName,expiryDate)
{
    this->amount=amount;
    this->companyName=companyName;
    this->PIN=PIN;
}

void CallingCard::display()
{
    Card::display();
    cout<<"Amount: "<<this->amount<<endl;
    cout<<"Company Name: "<<this->companyName<<endl;
    cout<<"PIN: "<<this->PIN<<endl;
}
```

IDCard.h

This is a another child class inheriting from base class

```
#include"Card.cpp"
#ifndef IDCARD_H
#define IDCARD_H
class IDCard :
        protected Card
{
    private:
    int CNICNumber;
    int age;
    public:
    IDCard(int cardNumber, string ownerName, string expiryDate, int CNICNumber=0, int age=0);
    string getExpiryDate() const;
    void display();

};
#endif
```

IDCard.cpp

```
#include"IDCard.h"
IDCard::IDCard(int cardNumber, string ownerName, string expiryDate, int CNICNumber, int age):Card(cardNumber,ownerName,expiryDate)
{
    this->CNICNumber=CNICNumber;
    this->age=age;
}
void IDCard::display()
{
    Card::display();
    cout<<"CNIC Number: "<<this->CNICNumber<<endl;
    cout<<"Age: "<<this->age<<endl;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include"CallingCard.cpp"
#include"IDCard.cpp"
int main()
{
    CallingCard card(1234, "Sana", "10-2-2018", 1000, "Warid", 444);
    card.display();


    IDCard idCard(1234, "Sana", "10-2-2018", 35202, 29);
    idCard.display();



}
```

Comment: What command are you using to compile this?

Comment: Header guards generally appear first, before any includes. Don't `#include "...cpp"`, you should only be including header files. When compiling, you should be able to do something like `clang++ *.cpp`

Comment: g++ Main.cpp
and then offcourse
/Users/sanayounas/Desktop/a.out

Comment: @ChrisMM I am just a second semester student yet so i am not sure what is that 

Comment: "I am not being able to properly implement them" - why not? What error did you get? The one about undefined references seems unrelated.

Comment: @underscore_d I am getting redefinition thing

Comment: what is "string.h"?

Comment: @MikeVine same as cstring

Comment: @SanaYounas I see. Do you need it? I'd think you'd need `#include <string>` to get the C++ string. I dont see you doing c-style string manipulation anywhere.

Comment: @MikeVine Here I have just added a piece of code because it is just the header guard I need help with so I didn't want to over populate things...

Answer (score 2):

Header-Guards must guard the whole file, so they must be the first and last thing:

```
// Nothing before the guard
#ifndef NAME_OF_HEADER
#define NAME_OF_HEADER

// All the stuff (also all of the includes!)

#endif
// Nothing after the guard
```

or just

```
// Nothing before the guard
#pragma once

// All the stuff
```

which is not part of the standard but supported by most compilers.

Secondly *never* include `.cpp`-files. Only include headers.

Comment: #pragma once in main file [-Wpragma-once-outside-header]
I am not sure what this means?

Comment: @SanaYounas, `-Wpragma-once-outside-header` is a warning (`W`) about `pragma once` being outside a header file, which means that `#pragma once` should _not_ be outside a header file.

Comment: but I have added #pragma once in ".h" file only?

Comment: Also if I add ".h" in main, it gives me the error I have mentioned on the top. I am using visual studio code

Comment: One thing at a time... Move all your guards to before you include other headers, then say whether it works.

Comment: I got the answer. so basically it wasn't anything wrong with the header guards or so.. It was the inclusion of ".cpp" file instead of ".h" file. I am using a macbook with VSC. what happens is that I because in VSC there isn't created a project as in VS therefore, I need to compile all ".cpp" files explicitly. 
So what I did now is in main, I have included ".h" file instead of using ".cpp" (which was wrong) and used the command

g++ Card.cpp CallingCard.cpp IDCard.cpp main.cpp  -o a.out
It did wonders.

Comment: Header guards **should** guard the whole file, but the guards in the question will work correctly, at the cost of extra `#include` directives that could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. so basically it wasn't anything wrong with the header guards or so, I mean ofcourse those should be included too, but also It was the inclusion of ".cpp" file instead of ".h" file. I am using a macbook with VSC. what happens is that I because in VSC there isn't created a project as in VS therefore, I need to compile all ".cpp" files explicitly. So what I did now is in main, I have included ".h" file instead of using ".cpp" (which was wrong) and used the command g++ Card.cpp CallingCard.cpp IDCard.cpp main.cpp -o a.out It did wonders.